# Must a mutex be unlocked before its containing structure be kmem_cache_free'd?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, mutex, linux-device-driver

Inside a linux kernel driver must a mutex be unlocked before being free'd and returned to the cache? I'm assuming it must be, providing nothing underlying kmem_cache does it itself!?

Comment: I don't know if it is different for kernel device drivers. But assuming you use pthread_mutex_t, according to `man phtread_mutex_destroy` you should unlock them in order to call pthread_mutex_destroy on them.

Comment: It's possibly different in kernel driver world to what I'm used to. kmem_cache_free doesn't actually free the memory, but returns it to a cache. So the mutex is still valid, at least until it's reaped, the question is whether it gets unlocked by the free, the reaping, or neither... I'm assuming neither, it seems only sensible to me that the mutex must be unlocked (in a known state) before being returned to the cache. But I thought I'd check with the collective!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it must.

The code [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/slab.c#L3772) (if using the slab allocator) will even try to figure out if you have some locks in the object you free, and [tell you](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/lockdep.c#L4068) that you have a bug if they're still locked.